# How to load several UIView in Split View Controller Base on cell in UITableView in iPad iOS 9 Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios9, uisplitviewcontroller

I have **spilt view controller** in iPad and using *UITableView* for load details base on tap on cell.
I want to load **diffrent** UiView in *storyboard* with tap on cells.
I am using iOS9 and Objective C.
Thank you.

Comment: Hope this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/4844/uisplitviewcontroller#t=201609010614478223695

Comment: Have any doubts regarding this ping me